# Why was one of my answers marked as spam with no apparent justification?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

One of my answers was marked as such with no apparent justification.

This subtracted 100 points from my reputation score.  Downvotes are one thing.  But marking an answer as spam when it is on topic, was previous upvoted by other users and doesn't promote any particular financial institution seems gratuitous and punitive.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused as well.  Can you link to the answer or at least the question where this happened?

Comment: It was this:  http://money.stackexchange.com/a/14722  ... appears to have been a mistake.

Comment: The post history shows "Community"; doesn't provide any detail why it was flagged.  Hmm.  I've undeleted & unlocked the answer, but I'm still puzzled.  Sorry about this!

Comment: FWIW, that question has attracted other spam answers.  There are two other deleted answers, both spam from Jan 29 and Jan 30.  I'd guess somebody flagged the wrong post.  Probably **me**, since I'm the one who marked the question as protected.  I'm really sorry about that!

Comment: .. I am *very* sorry about this, really!  I'll be more careful handling the flags next time.

Comment: I cleared the spam flags on the answer and it looks like that reversed the reputation penalty. (cc @ChrisW.Rea - there's an option to "clear flags" under the mod menu that apparently works differently than dismissing the flag from the flag queue would. :))

Comment: Yay, reputation returned!!!

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you! Did not know that was available. I appreciate it.

Comment: Wow that was a super-fast fix.  Thanks Chris!